How to add v-select sorting the v-data-table content and alignment for the same using vuejs 3
How I want the v-data-table to be displayed:

But v-data-table contents and headers are displayed as well:

This has to be achieved for mobile devices only.
Code for v-data-table:
<v-data-table
  v-if="makeDevicelist"
  :headers="makeHeaders"
  :items="makeDevicelist"
  :items-per-page="10"
  :item-class="itemRowBackground"
  :key="makeDevicelist.deviceId"
  :items-per-page-options="itemsPerPageOptions"
  items-per-page-text="表示件数:"
  :single-select="true"
  item-key="deviceId"
  show-select
  v-model="selectedItems"
  @click:row="OnClick"
  class="elevation-0 mb-10"
  :footer-props="footerProps"
  @pagination="paginate"
  :loading="isGettingDeviceLists"
  @update:options="updateOptions"
  return-object
>
  <template v-slot:top="{ pagination, options, updateOptions }">
    <v-data-table-footer
      :pagination="pagination"
      :options="options"
      @update:options="updateOptions"
      :items-per-page-text="itemsPerPageText"
      :items-per-page-options="itemsPerPageOptions"
      :show-first-last-page="true"
      id="d-table-header"
    >
    </v-data-table-footer>
  </template>

  <!-- for removing select all checkbox from device list -->
  <template v-slot:[`header.data-table-select`]></template>

  <template v-slot:[`item.icon`]="{ item }">
    <td><v-img :src="selectIcon(item)" contain width="50px"></v-img></td>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:[`item.deviceName`]="{ item }">
    <td :style="switchNameStyle(item)">{{ item.deviceAndUserNameStr }}</td>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:[`item.cocoroOfficeId`]="{ item }">
    <td :style="switchNameStyle(item)">{{ item.cocoroOfficeId }}</td>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:[`item.lastAccessTimeString`]="{ item }">
    <td :style="switchSizeStyle(item)">{{ item.lastAccessTimeString }}</td>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:[`item.backupSizeString`]="{ item }">
    <td :style="switchSizeStyle(item)">{{ item.backupSizeString }}</td>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:[`item.localUpdateTimeString`]="{ item }">
    <td :style="switchSizeStyle(item)">{{ item.localUpdateTimeString }}</td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>

Code to display header:
const makeHeaders = computed((): any => {
      let header;
      let headers2;

      if (deviceStore.currentMode == "FAX") {
        header = [
          {
            title: "デバイス名:",
            value: "deviceName",
            key: "deviceName",
            width: "50%",
          },
          {
            title: "ファイル数:",
            value: "deviceBackupFileNum",
            key: "deviceBackupFileNum",
            width: "50%",
          },
          {
            title: "最終受信日時:",
            key: "lastAccessTimeString",
            value: "lastAccessTimeString",
            width: "50%",
          },
          {
            title: "使用量:",
            value: "backupSizeString",
            key: "backupSizeString",
            width: "50%",
            sortable: false,
          },
        ];

        headers2 = [
          {
            title: "",
            value: "icon",
            key: "icon",
            width: "5%",
            sortable: false,
            class: "px-0",
          },
          {
            title: "デバイス名",
            value: "deviceName",
            key: "deviceName",
            width: "30%",
          },
          {
            title: "ファイル数",
            value: "deviceBackupFileNum",
            key: "deviceBackupFileNum",
            width: "30%",
          },
          {
            title: "最終受信日時",
            value: "lastAccessTimeString",
            key: "lastAccessTimeString",
            width: "25%",
          },
          {
            title: "使用量",
            value: "backupSizeString",
            key: "backupSizeString",
            width: "10%",
            sortable: false,
          },
        ];
      } else {
        header = [
          {
            title: "デバイス名 (ユーザー名):",
            value: "deviceName",
            key: "deviceName",
            width: "50%",
          },
          {
            title: "COCORO OFFICE ID:",
            value: "cocoroOfficeId",
            key: "cocoroOfficeId",
            width: "50%",
          },
          {
            title: "最終バックアップ日時:",
            key: "lastAccessTimeString",
            value: "lastAccessTimeString",
            width: "50%",
          },
          {
            title: "使用量:",
            key: "backupSizeString",
            value: "backupSizeString",
            width: "50%",
            sortable: false,
          },
        ];

        headers2 = [
          {
            title: "",
            key: "icon",
            value: "icon",
            width: "5%",
            sortable: false,
            class: "px-0",
          },
          {
            title: "デバイス名 (ユーザー名)",
            key: "deviceName",
            value: "deviceName",
            width: "30%",
          },
          {
            title: "COCORO OFFICE ID",
            key: "cocoroOfficeId",
            value: "cocoroOfficeId",
            width: "30%",
          },
          {
            title: "最終バックアップ日時",
            key: "lastAccessTimeString",
            value: "lastAccessTimeString",
            width: "25%",
          },
          {
            title: "使用量",
            key: "backupSizeString",
            value: "backupSizeString",
            width: "10%",
            sortable: false,
          },
        ];
      }

      if (Width.value < 600) {
        return header;
      }
      return headers2;
    });

If I add conditions to display headers this is not fixed.
The vuetify version used is "vuetify": "3.5.18".

You can use the mobile prop of VDataTable to change its display mode (available since v3.6.0, please upgrade your vuetify).
Here is an example, resizing the pane to see the effect:
https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVUMtOwzAQ/JVVLgGpL8QttKBK/Yu2ByfeUIPjtWwnbRTl31k7tISLV56ZnR3Ncci8q9Z7a1ddi1mRbQM2VouA7ycDsO2WUgSxDKLUCIVi0u9OWZqnDIqGSqWREd/sjTzQ1TC65tXteubDX185ZQN4DK1Nzqqx5AIM4LCGEWpHDeQcIf9Hth4PyrNPP9cEVfesi8qKjI/Cx33W7WZrT89zXcrN/DFCAMM0AGqiAvJSuHxxh6j8KthXEnqmwkV5KB2K73wB/DGfEf3IYXwsNCRRxxXrqFMSXXTU4vKnmeY5ljPV8VtN6LlbX5FFmapZcdgglEF3T1iSS4YOJbzYG3jSSr5N3FXJcCngdbOxtwSN6UA0ZbdsXJhW6/ScfwCuHqMi

Is there any other method, as of now I am not changing the version of Vuetify

@RakshithGanga What's your reason for pining the version? No breaking change was introduced in v3.6

I am adding 3 v-data-tables in different places, where this fix needs to be added only in one place.
If I modify vuetify version, then the v-data-table is changed in all places.

Is it possible to modify vuetify version for each data table that is being used.

You can turn off mobile mode for the other two v-data-table. :mobile="false"

If I make use of this method the UI is fixed properly, but the checkbox for the header is shown.
How can I remove the checkbox, I even am making use of select-strategy:"single" prop, and the header checkbox should not be present at all. So, if it is possible to remove it do suggest a solution.

select-strategy should work. Please give a minimal reproduction if you find a bug. Or you can hide the checkbox in the header via CSS
